# incrementar de 3 en tres en java

Tags: java

Buenas tengo un pequeño problema tengo esto:

```
while(leer.hasNextLine()) {
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(leer.nextLine(), ",");
  String n = st.nextToken();
  vert.add(n);  
}

for(int i=0; i<vert.size(); i+3) {
  for(int j = 1; j<vert.size(); j+3) {

  }
}
```

Pero me da error en `i+3`  y en `j+3`.

El error es este:

> Syntax error on token "+", invalid AssignmentOperator

Es que quiero que me lea de un fichero y me lo separe porque tiene (",") y quiero poner cada token dentro del `ArrayList` para recorrerlo y formar un grafo.

Comment: Prueba así `j = j  + 3`

Comment: Donde le indicas por ejemplo `0 = 0 + 3` la primer vuelta y en la siguiente `3 = 3 + 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando deseas aumentar el indice en mas de uno (90% de las veces usamos i++), debes de colocarlo como una asignación de valor, por ejemplo i += 3 o i = i + 3. Por lo cual quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i += 3) {
    for(int j = 1; j < vert.size(); j += 3) {
        // tu codigo aqui
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

La forma correcta es `i+=3 j+=3` o `i=i+3 j=j+3`

Quedaría así:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i += 3) {
    for(int j = 1; j < vert.size(); j += 3) {

    }
}
```

o

```
for(int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i = i + 3) {
    for(int j = 1; j < vert.size(); j = j + 3) {

    }
}
```